# Fermat's little Theorem and root power sums.

Tags: number-theory, symmetric-polynomials

Let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be monic of degree $n\ge 1$, and suppose $f$ factors as
$$
f=(x-r_1)\cdots (x-r_n)
$$
where $r_1,...,r_n$ are algebraic integers.

For each positive integer $k$, let
$$
s_k=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^k
$$
By properties of symmetric functions of the roots, each $s_k$ is an integer.

We have the following analog of Fermat's little Theorem . . .

**Claim:**$\;$If $p$ is prime, then $p{\,\mid\,}(s_p-s_1)$.

**Proof:**

Let $p$ be a prime.$\;$Then
\begin{align*}
s_p-s_1&=
\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^p-\sum_{i=1}^n r_i
\\[4pt]
&\equiv
\left(\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i\Bigr)^p-\sum_{i=1}^n r_i\right)\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
&\equiv
0\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the proof of the claim.

Next consider $(s_{p-1}\;\text{mod}\;p)$ . . .

If $p$ is prime and $r_1,...,r_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are such that $p{\,\not\mid\,}r_i$ for all $i$, then by Fermat's little Theorem we have $s_{p-1}\equiv n\;(\text{mod}\;p)$.

I'll conjecture a sort of converse . . .

**Conjecture:**$\;$If the congruence $s_{p-1}\equiv n\;(\text{mod}\;p)$ holds for all but finitely many primes $p$, then $r_1,...,r_n\in\mathbb{Z}{\setminus}\{0\}$.

**Question:**$\;$Does the conjecture hold?

Comment: This is a very nice conjecture +1 ! You must be the one my mentor mentioned. @quasi